# Visual Studio Code (1.18) plugin install

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is anyone could confirm that is not possible to install offline .visx plugins on recent VSC?

I'cant do that on 1.18, but on 1.17.2 it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the cli `code --install-extension <path to vsix file>` to install any extension.

You obviously should have already downloaded the vsix before doing that and also have code in your path.